# Spark dataFrame doesn't have createGlobalTempView() function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm using spark2.3 and scala 2.11.

1. I created dataFrame and can use createOrReplaceTempView() function.
2. But seems createGlobalTempView() function is missing, intellij says it can't find such method, nor could the intellisense give me the list.

So I wish to know if this method is obsoleted?(compatibility issue?)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createGlobalTempView()` Fuction also inuse  [ApiDoucment](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset)  also  have it  .
here is the [sourceCode](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.scala)  nearly  line 3115 .
Give you  a demo to handle  your  data.

```
val spark = SparkSession.
  builder.
  appName("Simple Application").
  master("local").
  getOrCreate()

val df = spark.read.json("my.json")
// Register the DataFrame as a SQL temporary view

df.createOrReplaceTempView("people1")//：people

val sqlDF = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM people1 ")

println("createOrReplaceTempView")

sqlDF.show()

// Register the DataFrame as a global temporary view
df.createGlobalTempView("people2")

// Global temporary view is tied to a system preserved database `global_temp`

val sqlDF2 = spark.sql("SELECT * FROM global_temp.people2")

sqlDF2.show()
```

Comment: run  with  spark 2.3.2 and scala  2.11

Comment: I am using spark2.3.1 and scala 2.12. Is it still old?

Comment: @HindForsum  The fuction  is  created since 2.1.0   version2.3.1 is ok ,it may caused by your dependency , if you set correct ,you will get the 'org.apache.spark:spark.sql_2.11:2.3.1'  jar  in your project libraries , you can see the source Code & find , If you also has problems  ,show your pom.xml if it's maven project